# MVC deploy IIS 7 Relative Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I'm try deploy mvc application to IIS7 but when I run my site it no load imagens and css, but when I run my site in vs2010 integrated with iisexpress work fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded locations to those CSS files in your views instead of using URL helpers, haven't you?

You wrote in your view:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Everything is hardcode, but in production and in the iisexpress is working fine. When I publish in IIS6 no works.

Comment: @DiegoDias, in your question you talked about IIS7. Now you talk about IIS6. So what is it? Could you be a little more precise?